# Re-formatting a text file

Tags: python, string, text

I am fairly new to `Python`. I have a text file, full of common misspellings. The correct spelling of the word is prefixed with a `$` character, and all misspelled versions of the word preceding it; one on each line.

`mispelling.txt`:

```
$year
eyar
yera
$years
eyars
eyasr
yeasr
yeras
yersa
```

I want to create a new text file, based on `mispelling.txt`, where the format appears as this:
`new_mispelling.txt`:

```
eyar->year
yera->year
eyars->years
eyasr->years
yeasr->years
yeras->years
yersa->years
```

The correct spelling of the word is on the right-hand side of its misspelling, separated by `->`; on the same line.

---

**Question:**

How do I read in the file, read `$` as a new word and thus a new line in my output file, propagate an output file and save to disk?

The purpose of this is to have my collected data be of the same format as this open-source Wikipedia entry [dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Lists_of_common_misspellings/For_machines) of *"all"* commonly misspelled words, that doesn't contain my own entries of words and misspellings.

Comment: You might want to check this out: https://github.com/filyp/autocorrect

Comment: You've told us what you *want* to do ... that's a story, not a question. Could you please rephrase your question so that it can be answered as an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question?

Comment: Sure thing. Let me know if I need to update my post further. @MikeScotty

Comment: Fair I'll try at this further. I assumed god-awful code would be bad. I do feel as though I've conveyed my problem and have laid out my post as best as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you process the file line-by-line, if you find a word that starts with `$`, set that as the "currently active correct spelling". Then each subsequent line is a misspelling for that word, so format that into a string and write it to the output file.

```
current_word = ""
with open("mispelling.txt") as f_in, open("new_mispelling.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        line = line.strip() # Remove whitespace at start and end 
        if line.startswith("$"):
            # If the line starts with $
            # Slice the current line from the second character to the end
            # And save it as current_word
            current_word = line[1:] 
        else:
            # If it doesn't start with $, create the string we want
            # And write it. 
            f_out.write(f"{line}->{current_word}\n")
```

With your input file, this gives:

```
eyar->year
yera->year
eyars->years
eyasr->years
yeasr->years
yeras->years
yersa->years
```

The `f"{line}->{current_word}\n"` construct is called an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) and is used for string interpolation in python 3.6+.

Comment: Thank you. I will spend time trying to actively understand it more and I may very well alter this for the future.

Comment: Sorry, this seems to be in reverse order. You're output is actually "correct->incorrect". I want "incorrect->correct"

Comment: I edited my answer just before you accepted it. It's as easy as changing the f-string in the `f_out.write()` line. @StressedBoi_69420

Answer (score 0):

A regex solution:

You can use the pattern `'\$(\w+)(.*?)(?=\$|$)'` and join each value starting with `$` with the subsequent values by `->`, then join all these by `\n` for the  groups captured, then finally join all such values by `\n`. Make sure to use `re.DOTALL` flag since its a multi-line string:

```py
import re
txt='''$year
eyar
yera
$years
eyars
eyasr
yeasr
yeras
yersa'''

print('\n'.join('\n'.join('->'.join((v, m.group(1)))
                          for v in m.group(2).strip('\n').split('\n')) for m in
                re.finditer('\$(\w+)(.*?)(?=\$|$)', txt, re.DOTALL)))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
eyar->year
yera->year
eyars->years
eyasr->years
yeasr->years
yeras->years
yersa->years
```

I'm leaving file read/write for you assuming that's not the problem you are asking for

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try this out with my input file.

Comment: This solution works great as a short and sweet one-liner. I got read in as well as write out working.